# How I can use performSegue in swift 3.0?

Tags: swift, segue

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewHistory: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewGoal: UIView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapHistory = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(goHistory))
        tapHistory.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapHistory.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        tapHistory.isEnabled = true
        viewHistory.addGestureRecognizer(tapHistory)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @objc func goHistory(){

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue_History", sender: self)

    }
```

[image]

In StoryBoard A, I set the Triggered Segues to MyPage->History.
So I set the segue identifier "Segue_History"

When I tap the view in MyPage, goHistory function call performSegue.

But it occurs error like this.

```
    2018-11-02 16:43:45.875605+0900 
testApp[1729:436205] 
-[testApp.VC_History tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x106a83d40
    2018-11-02 16:43:45.891627+0900 
testApp[1729:436205] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[testApp.VC_History tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x106a83d40'
```

I think I set the identifier at segue, but it is not.
Do you have any idea of it?

Comment: I think you need to check your tableView method or identifier

Comment: As the error suggest, problem should be related to `VC_History`'s `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` method. You should check that.

Comment: The error suggest you have a `UITableView` on `VC_History`, but didn't implement all the `UITableViewDatasource` methods.

Comment: @wings oops yes you're right

Comment: @RickyMo yes I was mistaken.

Comment: @Larme Yes I got it thanks